# JSON.parse, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

So, I'm trying to parse some JSON in Javascript. This feels like it should work, but I'm getting an error. Here's the function call:

```
JSON.parse("{player: 'green', direction: 'north'}");
```

And here's the error

```
VM156:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

I'm trying this on an empty web page, no JS libraries are present.

The string, just executed as Javascript creates an object with the two expected attributes.

I've tried wrapping the keys in strings. That didn't parse.

The unexpected token appears to be whatever the first letter is.

What am I doing wrong, how can I parse this object?

Comment: You're not passing it JSON, which is a problem for a function expecting JSON

Comment: @adeneo Possiblyt this doesn't do what I expect. Can you give a valid example?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is your friend, as is the spec at http://json.org

Comment: In JSON, keys and values are quoted with doublequotes, always, unless the values are numbers or other "objects" etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that JSON is more strict than javascript notation when creating objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not [valid JSON](http://json.org/).

Try this:

```
JSON.parse('{"player": "green", "direction": "north"}');
```

**Note the double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` and the quotes around the object keys.**